# Query in Oracle to get columns in a table with primary key info

Tags: oracle, primary-key

What is a query to get table description with columns with columns part of primary key tagged?  For instance, it would return something like this:

```
Table   Column       is_part_of_pk
-----   ------       -------------
ADDRESS  ID           1
ADDRESS  ADDR_LINE_1  0
ADDRESS  ADDR_CITY    0
STUDENT  FIRST_NAME   1
STUDENT  LAST_NAME    1
STUDENT  CLASS_NAME   0
```

*All* the columns in a table are listed and the ones that are or are part of a primary key are 'tagged'.  I have tried to select against user_tab_columns, all_cons_columns and all_constraints but i get duplicate columns.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
select col.table_name , col.column_name, 
case when exists(select 'x' from USER_CONSTRAINTS l 
join USER_CONS_COLUMNS ll on LL.CONSTRAINT_NAME = L.CONSTRAINT_NAME
where l.table_name = col.table_name and l.constraint_type = 'P' and ll.column_name = col.column_name) then 1 else 0 end is_part_of_pk
 from USER_TAB_COLUMNS col where table_name = :some_table_name
 order by column_id;
```

Comment: and maybe also better to add scheme :)